# How to use container exits immediately after startup in docker?

Tags: docker

As everyone knows, we can use `docker start [dockerID]` to start a closed container.

But, If this container exits immediately after startup. What should I do?

For example, I have a MySQL container, it runs without any problems. But the system is down. At next time I start this container. It tell me a file is worry so that this container immediately exit.
Now I want to delete this file, but this container can not be activated, so I can't enter this container to delete this file. What should I do?

And if I want to open bash in this state container, What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the container and launch a new one.

```
docker rm dockerID
docker run --name dockerID ... mysql:5.7
```

Containers are generally treated as disposable; there are times you're required to delete and recreate a container (to change some networking or environment options; to upgrade to a newer version of the underlying image).  The flip side of this is that containers' state is generally stored outside the container filesystem itself (you probably have a `docker run -v` or Docker Compose `volumes:` option) so it will survive deleting and recreating the container.  I almost never use `docker start`.

Creating a new container gets you around the limitations of `docker start`:

- If the container exits immediately but you don't know why, `docker run` or `docker-compose up` it without the `-d` option, so it prints its logs to the console
- If you want to run a different command (like an interactive shell) as the main container command, you can do it the same as any other container,

  ```
  docker run --rm -it -v ...:/var/lib/mysql/data mysql:5.6 sh
  docker-compose run db sh
  ```
- If the actual problem can be fixed with an environment variable or other setting, you can add that to the startup-time configuration, since you're already recreating the container